# xarray firing a Future Warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

Just upgraded to python3.8, I have updated xarray to v.0.16, but now I am always getting this warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/xarray/core/common.py:1123: FutureWarning: 'base' in .resample() and in Grouper() is deprecated.
The new arguments that you should use are 'offset' or 'origin'.

>>> df.resample(freq="3s", base=2)

becomes:

>>> df.resample(freq="3s", offset="2s")

  grouper = pd.Grouper(
```

The only point in my script in which I am using .resample is this:

```
mydata = xr.open_dataset(ncfile).resample(time='3H').reduce(np.mean)
```

but I don't know how to change it to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until this is updated in xarray, warnings can be ignored with a call to [`warnings.filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings).

You're welcome to open an issue on GitHub for xarray (or even a PR!)